# How to convert any type of format data into string

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have ajax call. That ajax give any type of data like xml, json.

```
 success: function(data) {
console.log(data)
}
```

I have to convert any type of format data into string in jquery.

Comment: data.toString() will help you?

Comment: xml data not converting

Comment: it depends on the data type you choose in the parameter of the ajax call

Comment: I sent any type of format. I am using accept:*/*. So i can send any type data. But My need is convert into string

Comment: @MohaideenIsmail You want to convert response objects into string?

Comment: yes @Jenson. For all format of resonse

Answer (score 0):

If the response is JSON object - Try

```
alert(JSON.stringify(ajaxResponse));
```

If the response is XML - Try

```
function xmlToString(xmlData) { 

    var xmlString;
    //IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlString = xmlData.xml;
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else{
        xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
    }
    return xmlString;
}   

alert(xmlToString(ajaxResponse));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have using following code for my solution

```
if(typeof data=="undefined") console.log(data);
       elseif(typeof data=="object")
       try
       {
               console.log((new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(data));
       }
       catch(e)
       {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
       }
       else console.log(data);
```